# SqlException after moving connection string to web.config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have to change my data source to the name of my server `[server name]\SQLExpress` after moving my connection string from `Page_Load` to `web.config`. Otherwise I get an `SqlException` at `con.Open()`. The app works fine both ways am just wondering why I need to change the datasource name after moving the connection string.

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CS"
      connectionString="data source=[server name]\SQLEXPRESS;  Initial Catalog = SampleDb; integrated security = true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>


 (string cs = "data source=.\\SQLExpress; initial catalog = SampleDb; integrated security= true";)-moved to web.config

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;

       //pass the connection string to the SqlConnection() constructor
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);

        //tell sqlcommand what query to execute and which connection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Electronics", con);

        //open connection
        con.Open();

        //execute the command
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        //close the connection
        con.Close();
```

Comment: You still have to read the connection string into a local variable.   Update to show your code after moving the string to web.config and include the error.

Comment: Try `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);`

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns `[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. `

Comment: assuming `[server name]` is an actual server then I would guess you don't have access or visibility to it.  Your original code has a dot as the server name.  If you put that in your web.config file I suspect that it will work.

Comment: @No Refunds No Returns .\\SQLExpress doesnt work in webconfig but it worked when I was hard coding in Page_Load. tried .\SQLExpress and that does work in webconfig. So .\SQLExpress and [server name]\SQLExpress both work in webconfig. Ive only been working with sql-server and db's for a little over a week now so im throughlly confused now.

Comment: in code you have to escape the backslash.  in web.config you don't.  In your code  `var cs = @".\SQLexpress ..."` or in web.config as you have it.  Your confusion is around using strings in C#, not SQL Express.